# Zoom in at splash screen of my appication in titanium is not working

Tags: titanium

I want my application splash screen to zoom in but unable to find any way to do so i am working in appcelerator studio

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing,set your first window background to the same as the splash screen image.Do the whatever animation you want on that window and close window when done.

Comment: In that  case we had to wait for our splash screen to remove and than deal with with the next window so it will not look good as we been watch the whole screen and than it starts to zoom

Answer (score 0):

You can add an imageview with the splash screen on top of your start window. When splash screen is gone, the imageview remains and you can animate it how you want